# Mapping Data Flow in Data Factory doesn't ignore line-breaks in text-values of CSV files

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I have the following problem in Azure Data Factory:

In a ADLS I have a CSV file with a linebreak in a value:

```
A, B, C
a, b, c
a, "b
b", c
```

This CSV is loaded in a (CSV) Dataset (in ADF) with the following settings; first row is header, quote character double quote ("), column delimiter Comma (,), row delimiter (\r,\n, or \r\n) and escape char backslash ().

The "Preview Data" of the dataset seems to work correct and outputs a table with 2 rows. This is also the output I expect, as the overal structure of the data is preserved.
[image]

However, when I try to use this dataset in Mapping Data Flow and select "Data Preview" (in the source node directly), I get the following output:
[image]

The linebreak isn't ignored, even as the whole value is between double quotes. The overal structure of the data is now broken as one row is splitted into two.

I get this kind of data when I save an Excel file with linebreaks in some cells as CSV. How should I work around this problem? Should I save the Excel differently, should I try to delete all linebreaks before saving as CSV, or is there a way to let Data Factory solve this problem? Als why does the Preview Data function in a Dataset seems to work correct, where the Data Preview function in Mapping Data Flow does not?

Comment: The error only happens when an Excel file as CSV source dataset?

Comment: I am only using CSV files, as Excel files cannot be processed in ADF. They were original an Excel files, but saved as CSV.

Comment: I see. I tried the same operation and data flow works ok, please see my answer.

Comment: I have adjusted my question. Its now contains a print screen of the "Preview Data" Dataset. You can see the data exists of two rows and ignores the line break in the second row, because it is between parenthesis. This is what I'm looking for in Data Flow, only there does the parenthesis exception not seem to work and carries out the linebreak.

Comment: Second edit:  Replaced the print-screens into bigger pictures that involve the menus of ADF.

Comment: 2022 Update - My Dataflow issue fixed by setting row delimiter as Carriage return (\r) and without multi line setting. Best solution would be row delimiter as  \r\n but currently it's not working\supported. I'm using PSV files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and there is nothing different between Copy Active and Data Flow source settings.

I uploaded an csv file and changed the data to the same with you in my Blob storage.

Test.csv:

[image]

The result in **Copy active settings and data preview:**
[image]

The result in **Data flow source data settings and data preview:**
[image]
[image]

Please check your settings in your data flow.

Reference tutorial: [Export Table to CSV](https://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/01/sql-server-export-table-to-csv.html), it also works for Azrue SQL database.

**Update:**

I asked Azure Support for help, they tested and have the same error.

Azure Support replied me and give the reason:
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You input file "test.csv" is not correct. the third row should be `a,"b`. I want to explicitly indicate that I have a value between parenthesis with a linebreak.

Comment: @MichaelH. Sorry, I updated my answer. I changed the csv data but get the same result in Copy Active and Data Flow. I tested and they all works well, strange...Can you show us some screenshots of your steps?

Comment: I have added a bigger print-screen of the problem which shows the ADF menu's I'm working in. The problem arises in the "datafow" activity, where the line-break isn't recognized as being part of the value.

Comment: Hi @MichaelH. I updated my answer, Azure Support replied me. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @Lean Yue. That's great. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone facing the same issue, now Microsoft has enabled the multiline feature in data flow. Now we can use csv files with multiline values

[image]

And if you still having issues check this one

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide.md#error-code-df-executor-systeminvalidjson-1

Answer (score 2):

We are adding multi-line string handling to ADF Data Flows for text-delimited datasets. We'll have that feature enabled within a few iterations.

The workaround until then is to copy the data from your CSV to Parquet and then consume that Parquet dataset through your data flow source transformation.

Comment: Hello @MarkKromer, I have a similar usecase where my csv contains multiline data. But it is not under the double quotes. There are around 4000 csv files which are around 300 GB so can't really create them again with double quotes around them. So will the parquet conversion will work for me?